# How to create a rule in Outlook 365 if I am the only receiver

Tags: outlook

I have thousands of emails in Outlook 365 (ver. 15) and in most of them I am part of a group. I was wondering how to create a rule to isolate the email sent only to me directly. I mean when I am the only receiver of the email and no one else is in Cc or forwarded to.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose the "sent to me only" option when you create the rule:

[image]